# What does Allow : GET mean in a HTTP response header?

Tags: http, http-headers

What does `Allow: GET` mean below ?

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: spray-can/1.3.1
Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2016 12:54:34 GMT
Allow: GET
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 47
```

[image]

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.7

Comment: You POSTed but it wants a GET.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Controller to process the request on the backend,
Make sure to use the annotation @RestController instead of @Controller